# Lubuntu 18.10 refuses to install due to not having enough working memory

Tags: lubuntu

So I ran into an issue where my system refuses to install Lubuntu 18.10. It states that "at least 1 gb is required" of working memory, and I have 1 gb of ram. I'm upgrading from ubuntu 14.04, where I shredded everything clean and I booted lubuntu from a usb.

Is there a way to bypass this or do I have to install another iso? I though lubuntu was lighter than ubuntu, therefore the spec requirements are similar or less than ubuntu. Maybe that wasn't true?

Plus lubuntu is running fine on the usb, so why does it refuse to install? Really silly.

Comment: It isn't though. Completely different scenarios. I don't need to edit anything, pretty self explantory that my case is unique.

Comment: And mine is about installation due to the system, so why in the world is this solved through the threads? Not helpful.

Comment: From your question *It states that "at least 1 gb is required" of working memory, and I have 1 gb of ram* so **add more virtual working memory** by following the instructions in the duplicate question links. That's *why in the world this is solved through the threads* and that's why the duplicate questions are both helpful. Adding virtual RAM temporarily instead of buying more RAM sticks will save you money because old DDR RAM is expensive RAM.

Comment: Yeah but installing it doesn't add any ram or anything... None of the answers give a clear answer on how to change the ram too, it's all confusing. One says to type in swapoff, but it says that I'm not a superuser. I'm sorry for the rude reply to you earlier.

Comment: As I wrote in the previous comment zram is virtual RAM not physical RAM. swap space is used by the system instead of RAM when the system runs out of physical RAM. Elevating normal user privileges to superuser to run a command is achieved by prefacing that command with `sudo`.

Comment: The system shows the swap seperetaly, so it still says that "1gb" is required for installation.

Comment: Clearly zram didn't work, so I retracted my close vote and since there are no other close votes your question is returned back to square one.

Answer (score 2):

Open up terminal

Type : cd /etc/calamares/modules

You should be now at that directory

type : sudo chmod a+rwx welcome.conf

Now you should have permission to edit the ram block file, who ever implemented this block should lose there job

Type : featherpad welcome.conf

Should open the file and now change the 1 to a 0 next to requiredram

Then press files save and open the installer again,

This is how I bypassed the ram limit, and I’m a windows user... sad times

This has to be done, every time you boot up the installer, even if it’s the same usb stick, as any changes you make inside of the live environment get undone, so if a update bricks  your computer then welcome back to the second time of following this guide

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option over that provided by Signedadam would be to use the [*Ubuntu minimal CD*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

The **Ubuntu minimal CD** (`mini.iso`) provides a textual installer. You can select or deselect packages as you need them. Booting up the installed system will give you a command line terminal. You then can install a fully configured graphical desktop (and the entire graphic system) at once by installing the appropriate metapackage. To install Lubuntu, you need lubuntu-desktop: `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`.

This installer is textual rather than graphical. It also provide choices in menu's, so it is not particularly difficult to use. It requires few memory to run, so it is quite certain that you will not run into memory issues during installation.